# Windows 2003 DNS problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, dhcp

All of a sudden DNS resolution became problematic on the clients of my Windows 2003 SBS server. Websites displayed slowly, or were not found. I did not reconfigure the server in the last weeks myself. The clients were configured to get both their IP address and their DNS settings from the server. After I manually configured the clients' primary DNS to the server's IP and the secondary DNS to an outside DNS server the problem went away. The server has two network cards, one is connected to the net, the other connects to the clients. 
What can have gone wrong?
How can I configure the server to automatically push the right DNS settings to the clients? 
*or*
How do I correct the faulty DNS resolution in the server itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I configure the server to automatically push the right DNS settings to the clients?

These setting are provided by the DHCP server - first check the DHCP configuration on your Windows server, but since it worked before and you didn't mention messing with configuration I would guess that you might have added another DHCP server into your network. Have you installed any print server or a similiar network device that might have dhcp functionality enabled by default?

Comment: Well, the router, internet modem and print server all have a built in DHCP server, but I disabled them. Perhaps a reboot has reenabled them. I will doublecheck. I doubt that that is the cause of the problem though as the the DNS server that was automatically pushed was the win 2003 server itself. It seems that the server was no longer able to resolve DNS requests that originated from the internal LAN.

Comment: if you think that the problem lies directly in your DNS server then open its console and check what servers you have set up as forwarders - then check if these servers work.
Also check the Interfaces tab in Properties dialog to see if your server is listening on the internal intarface